# Не работает сильно приватное свойство в Python3 через __свойство, подскажите?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучаю Python3, дошел до инкапсуляции и тут я не могу понять.
Если правильно понял, то `__` у свойства класса говорит о том, что напрямую к этому методу обратиться через `obj.__variable` нельзя, правильно?

Но у меня не получается сделать приватным свойство, пробовал и через `__init__()`, и просто в теле класса `__` создавать.

Через сеттер-геттер нормально работает, но и напрямую через `obj.__variable` могут изменять и считывать значение.

Скажите пожалуйста, где я ошибся?
Не хочется идти дальше, не поняв этой важной темы.

Код:

```
# Создаем класс Auto
class Auto:
    # Инициализация
    def __init__(self):
        self.__number = ""
        print("Создали класс Auto")

    # Свойства
    # Номер автомобиля, сильно приватное свойство, т.к. __ префикс и обратиться напрямую нельзя через obj.__свойство
    #__number = ""

    # Сеттер
    def set_number(self, number):
        # Валидация данных
        if len(number) in [7, 8]:
            self.__number = number
        else:
            print("Номер автомобиля неправильный, задайте 7 или 8 цифр.")
    # Геттер
    def get_number(self):
        return self.__number

# Создаем объект Audi
audi = Auto()

# Задаем значение audi.__number через сеттер и считываем через геттер
audi.set_number("A777SD77")
print(audi.get_number())

# Пытаемся задать или прочитать свойство с сильной приватностью __number напрямую - нельзя, т.к. сильно приватное
audi.__number = "L123OX23"
print(audi.__number)

# Считываем значение изначального __number через геттер, а не созданного извне _Auto__number, оно не изменилось
print(audi.get_number())
```

Результат:

```
Создали класс Auto
A777SD77
L123OX23

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что на предпоследней строке (`audi.__number = …`) вы создаёте *новый* атрибут *извне*, точное имя которого `__number`.
Созданный вами атрибут `__number` *изнутри* класса на самом деле получает имя `_Auto__number`, что как раз и является показателем приватности.

Приватные атрибуты это не жёсткое правило, а просто соглашение. Если по каким-то причинам нужно получить доступ к такому атрибуту, то программист может это сделать.

Подробнее: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Comment: leovp, большое спасибо!
Теперь понятно :)

Я же потом смотрел значение уже нового свойства, а не через геттер, а через геттер значение старое, значит изначальный __number не изменился, а создалось новое свойство.

    # Считываем значение изначального __number через геттер, а не созданного извне _Auto__number, оно не изменилось
    print(audi.get_number())

Answer (score 3):

На будущее чтобы таких вопрос не возникало используйте `__dict__` для проверки, как и сказал предыдущий оратор вы создали еще один атрибут. Достаточно до присвоения и после вывести содержимое атрибутов объекта:

до присвоения:

```
__dict__ =  {'_Auto__number': 'A777SD77'}
```

после:

```
__dict__ =  {'_Auto__number': 'A777SD77', '__number': 'L123OX23'}
```