# Доступны закрытые атрибуты класса

Tags: python

Есть такой код, почему есть доступ к закрытым атрибутам?

```
class Point:
    """docstring"""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, f'__{key}', value)


pt = Point(x=0, y=10)
print(pt.__dict__)
print(pt.__x, pt.__y)
```

Вывод в консоль

```
{'__x': 0, '__y': 10}
0 10
```

То есть свойства закрытые, но через экземпляр класса я имею к ним доступ. Подскажите, где я не прав?

Comment: В питоне нет контроля доступа. "Закрытость" свойств через подчеркивание - всего лишь соглашение. И такое там везде. Например, никто не помешает вам перезаписать константы, а при определении class ... в купе с декоратором вместо класса получить хоть None

Comment: потому, что в питоне нет как таковой инкапсуляции - то что вы делаете хоть и являются "приватными" атрибутами, но они все еще будут доступны из экземпляра. единственное - такие поля у класса не неследуются

Comment: Спасибо, понятно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает сильно приватное свойство в Python3 через \_\_свойство, подскажите?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528478/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2-python3-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5)